# What is the correct way to use SECONDEXPANSION to set dependencies based on target-specific variables

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I would like to set dependencies based on target-specific variables and constructed the following test makefile using `SECONDEXPANSION`:

```
foo.h:
    touch foo.h
bar.h:
    touch bar.h

.SECONDEXPANSION:
baz.h: $$(HEADER_NAME)
    echo "In baz.h with HEADER_NAME = $(HEADER_NAME)"

foo: HEADER_NAME=foo.h
foo: baz.h
    file $(HEADER_NAME)
bar: HEADER_NAME=bar.h
bar: baz.h
    file $(HEADER_NAME)

clean:
    rm -f *.h
```

However I have multiple versions of GNU Make installed on my system and the makefile only works as expected on version 4.4.1. Versions 4.3 and 4.2.1 never run the targets for `foo.h` or `bar.h` (as if `HEADER_NAME` was empty when the second expansion was performed).

Have I used `SECONDEXPANSION` incorrectly and it only works by chance on v4.4.1 or is this an issue in the earlier versions of make I have installed? I'm confident that it isn't a newly added feature as the documentation of version 4.2.1 includes `SECONDEXPANSION`.

Comment: With a quick check it appears to be a problem that was fixed in GNU Make 4.4.  I checked older versions and only 4.4 and 4.4.1 work.  I think the current (4.4.x) behavior is correct.  I'd have to look more carefully at the older releases to see why they weren't working and what issue resolved this.  I suspect https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?62706

Comment: Excellent, I didn't find that bug report, thanks. Convert this to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @MadScientist Which behaviour would `make foo bar` evoke?

Comment: Since `foo` is built first it would create `baz.h` with `HEADER_NAME` set to `foo.h`.  When make goes to build `bar` it will see that `baz.h` already exists and so it won't try to rebuild it.

Comment: @Carcophan I beg the question if the functionality here is really a win. As you see (by the comment from MadScientist) you lose the information from which file `baz.h` is built. If the distinction is material to the correctness of either final target `foo` or `bar`, you invite an error here. Conversely, you could depend `baz.h` on both `foo.h` and `bar.h` and avoid the hassle with secondary expansion.

Comment: As so often is true in SO, the problem has been simplified to such a point that it's impossible for us to know if the real use-case is valid or not.  We just have to take the OPs word that whatever they are trying to do is useful and appropriate for their situation.

Comment: @Vroomfondel As observed, this is a very cut down example and in the full makefile trying to build both foo and bar in the same make invocation causes an error.

Comment: @Carcophan Please note that the error scenario also happens if you do not build both final targets in one `make` invocation: the sequence `touch foo.h; touch bar.h; make bar; make foo` is enough to cloak the newness of `foo.h` versus `baz.h` and its changes will never be incorporated into `baz.h`.